# TextView clickable is auto-enabling inside LinearLayout button

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, clickable, android-11

I've been having a really annoying issue ever since I updated my project to level 30 and android studio to 4.2. All my clickable views have a strange issue, I have some linearlayouts, relativelayouts set to clickable and with an onClickListener, this worked perfectly previous to this update.

But now when I try to click one of this layout buttons I can only click the outer part of the view and not any of the child components, for example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/basket_expand"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_green"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/dark_rounded_green"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/order_items"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/zero"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/basket_button_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/open_basket"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="$0"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In this view I cannot click over the three texts, just when I click the border of the linearlayout the click will trigger, I can see a press event called in the Profiler when clicking the textViews but the parent onClick event is not called.

I checked the layout inspector and inspite hardcoding clickable false for the textviews it still shows up as enabled:

From the xml:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

When running the app inside the layout inspector:

[image]

There's no place where I set the clickable to anything to true inside my kotlin code or any other part. I've tried enabling and disabling some attributes but nothing changes, for example descendantFocusability, setting clickable and focusable to false to the children, nothing seems to work. any ideas why this might be happening? Thanks.

*Edit:* If I click a random button and add to the onclick listener isClickable false to the textviews the parent view click works, but this is really cumbersome and it won't work on a recyclerview (one test case where this is happening)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just remove the:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

from the "LinearLayout", it's interfering with the others, and set the "TextView"  with:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

one more thing, it's possible that your rendering is not working properly so  instead try to set this values in the xml, NOT IN THE GRAPHIC VIEW!.